# Copying text of textarea into div with line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am tying to make a simple effect using `keyup()` in jQuery. I just want that when user types into the `textarea` then the text which user types will copy to another div named `.content`. When I press <kbd>enter</kbd> in textarea a new line is created but in my div the text is showing in the same line. My code is below or you can see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pqygp/

```js
    $('.content:not(.focus)').keyup(function(){     
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        
        $('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="mas" rows="15" class="content"></textarea>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="mas" >Texts Comes here</div>
```

Comment: Are you want to use javascript for this replace of jQuery?

Comment: Have any of the answers helped you? If so, please check it to complete this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to convert the literal newlines into `<br>` tags for proper output in the DIV.

```
$('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>'));
```

Shown in your code below:

```js
    $('.content:not(.focus)').keyup(function(){     
                                    
                                    
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        
        $('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>')); //convert newlines into <br> tags
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <textarea name="mas" rows="15" class="content"></textarea> <p>&nbsp;</p> <div class="mas" >Texts Comes here</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqygp/2/)

Comment: is there a safe way to do this? It's pretty pointless as is. While it does answer the question, all I have to do is type <script> .. any js I want.. </script> and it will run. So for user inputs, it's a bit dangerous if this content is displayed to multiple users

Comment: @user2330270 Yea, just use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 40):

Add a `white-space: pre-wrap` rule to the div's CSS.

```
.mas {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pqygp/13/

Comment: Please note only IE 8 and superior support this property. According to the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), you can use the properties `{
  word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;      /* current browsers */
}` for it to work with IE 6

Comment: I like this more, because it has a few lines and you can use ´.text()´ to display without html ´<br>´ reference.

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 5):

Use this line: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqygp/15/)

```
$('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value.replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));
```

The problem was that newlines don't create linebreaks in html, but `<br>` will.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
var value = $(this).();
var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');

$('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value.replace(/\r?\n/g,"<br>"));
```

This is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqygp/17/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use React:

```
render() {
  const nbOfTextareaRows = this.state.textareaValue.split('\n').length;

  return (
    <textarea
      value={this.state.textareaValue}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ textareaValue: e.target.value })}
      rows={nbOfTextareaRows}
    />
  );
}
```