# How do I make <div> into <textarea> copy to copy the line break too when hitting "enter keyboard button"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, enter

How do I make when copying  to  to copy the line break too when i push enter keyboard button so that it is an exact copy?
Right now it works, but it does not copy line break when pushing the enter keyboard button. And I want it to work as it does now without having it stripped.

**NOTE because of former misunderstanding I clarify it:** Please do not confuse "copying texatea into div" because that is not the same thing as "coping div into textarea", because the code working for "copying texatea into div" does not work the same as "coping div into textarea". I need to "coping div into textarea" and not the other way around.

**I want: div** into **text**

**NOT: text** into **div**

**JavaScript:**

```
function copyText() {
  $("#text").val($("#divtext").text())
}
```

**html:**

```
<textarea name="text" id="text" rows="14" cols="54" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145682/copying-text-of-textarea-into-div-with-line-breaks

Comment: That link you show me is copying textarea into div, this one is the "opposite" copying div into textarea. Not the same thing.

Comment: I have tried the link you gave me before I posted this. Id does not work correctly when copying from div to textarea. It works correctly only when copying textarea to div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to get line breaks from `div` if you use `.text()`, try using `.html()`

Split `<br>` from `div` and join using `\n` for `textarea`

`$('#text').val($('#divtext').html().split('<br>').join('\n'))`

Comment: Sorry bro I just noticed. You code is NOT good. It strips the code and I do not want it stripped.

Comment: Although if I wanted it stripped it is useful, yet it is not correct to what I want.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, your issue was of maintaining line breaks when you hit ENTER, the code only converts `<br>` to `\n` by using `.split()` and `.join()` -- NOT strip

Comment: I remade your code and managed to make it work. It simply strips out the html as default and then it strips in the html again so it shows the same copy result. I will post the answer to how I solved the problem for others to see.

Comment: Yes but it also split the source code. That was the problem. Yet by modifying your code, you helped me to solve the problem even though the code you gave me was incomplete.

Comment: The code you gave me does strip the source code put in the `<div>` box and it comes out stripped in the `<textarea>`. To solve that problem I simply added the codes to unstripp it, so the result in the `<textarea>` comes out exactly the same as in the `<div>` box.

Comment: When coping from `<div>` to `textarea` using "html()" instead of "text()" it will automatically strip the source codes put in the editable `<div>` box. To avoid that, I simply added codes to your idea to unstrip it after the default stripping made by the "html()".  How ever "text()" does not strip, but it does not add breaks either.

Comment: So thank you and using you answer I modified it a bit and made it work. I posed it as an answer called "UPDATE" so you and other can see what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the enter keydown also:

```js
<script>
function onTextChange() {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;

    // If the user has pressed enter
    if (key === 13) {
        document.getElementById("text").value = document.getElementById("text").value + "\n*";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="yourDiv" onkeypress="onTextChange();"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is that it does give me the " * " on a new line, but when copying the text I get the text back on the same line. How do I combine this code you gave me so that when typing the text continues on the line it put the " * " on? Because right now the only thing it does correctly is put the " * " on a new line, but then the rest of the text is still on the same line as it use to be and no change is made.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING UPDATE**

I used the code from an answer I got, but I had to modify it a bit to make it work properly because the answer I got was incomplete. Because I want the code copied but not stripped out, then what was needed to do is to let it strip out as default and then strip it in again so it shows as source codes when typing source codes, and not as a striped out text.

So here is the complete answer that worked and how I made it work out of the incomplete answer I got. This code works.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function copyText() {
  $('#text').val($('#divtext').html()
  .split('<br>').join('')
  .split('<div>').join('\n')
  .split('</div>').join('')
  .split('&lt;').join('<')
  .split('&gt;').join('>')
  .split('&nbsp;').join(' ')
  .split('&amp;').join('&')
  )
}
</script>

<div id="divtext" contentEditable="true" wrap="soft" style="text-align:left; width: 499px; height: 230px;" onkeyup="copyText();"></div>
<br>
<textarea id="text" rows="34" cols="134" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```