# HTML/Javascript - How to display text from input field as HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have a textarea on my webpage that users will enter HTML code in. I want to display that HTML code somewhere else on my webpage. How do I got about this?

Essentially I want to do what stack overflow does in their question asking text area where you can enter in HTML tags like strong and they will display appropriately like **this** when the text is displayed. Another example is that the user might enter an image tag and I would want that image to display in another part of the site.

I am using Node and Express on the backend with MongoDB to store the user input and ejs templates to display the HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145682/copying-text-of-textarea-into-div-with-line-breaks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying text of textarea into div with line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145682/copying-text-of-textarea-into-div-with-line-breaks)

Comment: Be very, very careful about going down that path.  The reason sites like SO and others don't just have people enter in HTML is that it's a big security risk.  You put your users at risk of a persistent XSS attack if you do this.  It's much safer to support a very limited set of markup which you transform into HTML markup yourself.

Comment: [Cross-site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Comment: The use entering the HTML is an admin user so I am not too worried about security. And I do not want to display the text in the text area as a string or text but instead as functioning HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#htmlinput").on("input",function(){
  $("#target").html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="htmlinput"></textarea>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: This sets the HTML of the element to the text entered in the text area but I want to display that text as functioning HTML code if that makes sense

Comment: @Adhaar Sharma - you mean displaying the input texts from textarea to html content even when trying to reload the page it will still remains? You need an ajax method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code. In my JS, I get the value from the textarea and displayed it to the div element with an id of `output` by using `.innerHTML` property. This property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

```js
function myInput(){
var y = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = y;    
}
```

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box; }
textarea{ width: 100%; }

#output{
  display:block;
  background:#489ae0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="please input your texts here" oninput="myInput()"/></textarea>
  <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

on js

```
function write() {
  var text = document.form.input.value;
  return document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = text;
}
```

on html

```
<form name="form">
<textarea onkeyup="write()" name="input"></textarea>
<div id="id"></div>
</form>
```